# How to transfer a save file from a computer to another?

Tags: hyper-light-drifter

Hyper Light Drifter apparently doesn't use Steam Cloud and therefore you have to copy/paste your save files somehow when you want to continue to play from a different computer.  Any idea where to find the save files and how to import them to another computer (any specific manipulation ?)

I'm playing the Steam version under Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save files locations:

**PC**: `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\HyperLightDrifter`
**Mac**: `/Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/com.HeartMachine.HyperLightDrifter` 
**Linux**: `/home/[username]/.config/HyperLightDrifter`

Source: http://trappar.github.io/hyperlightdrifter-transfer/

Answer (score 0):

Game save files are usually stored in a specific folder. The folder having a name similar to that of the game.
The folder can be found (most probably)  in either of the following paths:

- Default Documents directory
- Program data directory
- Game installation directory

If you are not able to find it then search for it by typing the name of the game in the search bar of your file manager.

If you find that folder, just copy it and paste it in a similar path in the other computer. For example if you find it in the Documents directory in one computer then copy and paste the folder in the Documents directory of the other computer. This way I guess you'll be able to continue your game campaign in the other computer